# puppetserver as client of another puppetserver

Tags: puppet

I have a puppet OS v6 install that maintains 'internal' server hosts. I've recently started migrating 'external' servers to a separate puppet domain. I'd like to include the 'external' domain server as a host in the 'internal' domain so I can use the base configuration that I have for other 'internal' hosts.

1. Is this practical / possible?
2. If so, how do I specify the 'agent' **ssldir** to keep it separated from the 'server' **ssldir**? Looks like there's only one ssldir setting in the [main] section of **puppet.conf**.

Why have different hosts? There are network / security reasons to separate the two onto different VMs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to include the 'external' domain server as a host in the
>   'internal' domain so I can use the base configuration that I have for
>   other 'internal' hosts.
>
> 1. Is this practical / possible?

It's definitely possible.  You'll have to judge how *practical* it is.

> 2. If so, how do I specify the 'agent' **ssldir** to keep it separated from the 'server' **ssldir**? Looks like there's only one
>      ssldir setting in the [main] section of **puppet.conf**.

Most Puppet settings can be specified in multiple sections, so one thing you could try would be to specify `ssldir` in the `[agent]` section.  For the agent only, that should override the the default and / or an explicit setting in the `[main]` section.

Alternatively, you can override the config file via command-line options. Specifically, you could use the `--ssldir` option (or, more broadly, the `--vardir` option) when you launch Puppet.

But do you really need a separate set of SSL certificates?  If you set up a central CA instead of having each server provide CA services for its clients, and maybe by other means as well, you ought to be able to have a single cert for each machine that it uses to identify itself to all other machines in your site.

Comment: `But do you really need a separate set of SSL certificates` - probably not. But Im a big chicken... and huge proponent of "if it aint broke..."